# WKHTMLTOPDF and "Error: Unable to create temporery file"

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I've written a piece of code in **PHP** to generate **PDF** using **WKHTMLTOPDF** binary file. It was working fine till I had to recompile my Apache. Now it fails with error `Error: Unable to create temporery file` (this is the exact wording).

The situation in which the error is reproducible is a little complicated. I managed to narrow down the error and now I'm pretty sure that the error happens because of the user that Apache runs as. It seems to me that when WKTHMLTOPDF is running as a user with no home folder, it's unable to access a temporary folder within the user's home folder.

Surely I can change the Apache's user but I would rather resolve this problem once and for all. To this end it would be great if I could somehow set the temp folder for WKHTMLTOPDF or at least print its current value to make it valid! Does anyone know how to do any of these two?

BTW, I'm using **WKHTMLTOPDF** 0.11.0 rc1.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error today in Rails4 + pdfkit gem(0.8.2) + wkhtmltopdf(0.12.2.1) under CentOS 6.7.

This error came from wkhtmltopdf and the reason was it couldn't create temporary file.  wkhtmltopdf depends on some temporary filename creation API (I'm not sure), but probably following shows some hints:

```
$ man tempfile 
$ man tempnam
```

In my case, my TMPDIR environment variable showed wrong path (I had accidentaly deleted the directory!) so that wkhtmltopdf couldn't create work file.

When I unset TMPDIR, then it worked!  Of course, setting correct existence directory to TMPDIR should be OK too.

Answer (score 0):

Saw the error under Amazon Linux 2 (AWS Lambda in my case) with Python-Pdfkit wrapped around wkhtmltopdf.

Adding the following options solved the issue.

```
pdf_bytes = pdfkit.from_string(
    ...
    options={
        "disable-local-file-access": "",
        "allow": "/tmp", # directory/file that has read/write access
    }
)
```

See [wkhtmlpdf usage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) for more information.

I got the hint from the above answer, but instead of setting the TMPDIR env variable, I restricted the folder that wkhtmltopdf can access.

Since AWS Lambda can only access /tmp, that’s what I allowed.

I guess wkhtmltopdf needs to write a temp file, and only allowing a directory that is read/write allowed solves the problem.